# Wpf Datagrid, collection in rows

Tags: wpf, list, collections, datagrid, row

I have to make such table

[Table to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFgaS.png)

First column is month number,
second column is number of days, 
third column is number of days.

and next 31 columns are decimal values.

So I want to bind a list of this values, so my wpf will be something like this:

```
<Grid>

 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">

   <DataGrid.Columns>


                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Month" Binding="{Binding Month}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="NumberOfDays" Binding="{Binding NumberOfDays}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="NumberOfHours" Binding="{Binding NumberOfHours}"/>


                //so here I`d like to have collection to 31 columns 




   </DataGrid.Columns>


 </DataGrid >
</Grid>
```

Any ideas how to make them?

Of course I can use grid and generate textblocks but this solution seems to be Non-elegant.

I want to do it inseide datagrid or similar.

Comment: make them in exactly the same way as `"Month"`, `"NumberOfDays"` ... columns

Answer (score 0):

You could either generate the columns programmatically:

```
for (int i = 1; i< 32; ++i)
{
    dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = i.ToString(), Binding = new Binding("Day" + i.ToString()) });
}
```

Or you could define them in your XAML markup:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Month" Binding="{Binding Month}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="NumberOfDays" Binding="{Binding NumberOfDays}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="NumberOfHours" Binding="{Binding NumberOfHours}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="1" Binding="{Binding Day1}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="2" Binding="{Binding Day2}"/>
    //and so on
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

You will need to add a public property per day (Day1, Day2, etc.) to the class where the `Month`, `NumberOfDays` and `NumberOfHours` properties are defined.